# I remember seeing a movie when I was young about a group of aliens being kept in a facility on Earth

Tags: story-identification

There were like 4 or 5 aliens of different types and one of them was really intelligent (and short) and had telekinesis and was working with the human scientists, while another one was called something like 'Subject Zero' and was either invisible or could shape shift I think. Some of the more savage aliens  escape and start killing the humans. 
I don't know if it was a blockbuster or not, but it was American.
I think this film might be from the 90s or early 2000s.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me find this movie again.

Comment: Was this a big blockbuster movie or a less popular movie? Do you have any other details about it?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Hopefully we can help you identify the answer to your question. To help us, what additional information can you provide about the movie?  E.g. can you remember any of the actors names that were in it? Did you see it in the theater or on TV? What did the aliens look like? Humanoid, insectoid, reptilian?  Did you see/hear it In the US/English or in another country/language? Any additional details you can remember could be helpful. Too, how did the movie end?  You can use spoiler flags if you want. But, did the aliens all get killed, kicked off the planet? Locked away?

Comment: I'm going to say I'm pretty sure this isn't a blockbuster.

Comment: The patient zero thing makes it sound like 51 (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/51_(film)), but that's only a few years old (2011). Patient Zero could shapeshift after touching someone.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the movie "[51](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/51_(film))".

Not Subject Zero but "Patient Zero" and it's been there 25 years, but it can shapeshift by touching someone.

There are several other aliens there as I recall that escape and it turns into a horror movie from a scifi.

The only thing against this idea is that the movie is more recent than you specified (came out in 2011)

Comment: Is it possible this one is a remake of an order film?

Comment: It's possible - searching on IMDB and Wikipedia don't turn up anything about it being a remake. I saw it recently on Netflix and the plot is pretty similar to what's described in the question